# Django papertrail logging failing mysteriously

Tags: django, logging, papertrail-app

I have set up papertrail for a Django project but logging fails with `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`. The weird thing is  if I call `django.setup()` before the logging call it works...

*settings.py*

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'json': {
            '()': 'pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter',
             'fmt': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s',
         },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'papertrail': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.SysLogHandler',
            'formatter': 'json',
            'address': ('logsN.papertrailapp.com', 12345)
         },
    ...
    },
    'loggers': {
        'papertrail': {
            'handlers': ['papertrail'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
         },
    ...
```

*/management/commands/logging_test.py*

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
import django
import logging

#  uncomment this line to make it work
#django.setup()


def test_logging():
    logger = logging.getLogger('papertrail')
    logger.error(
        'TEST LOGGING'
    )


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        test_logging()
```

I can call the test_logging function with:

```
./manage.py test_logging
```

If I uncomment the line `django.setup()` it works. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#django.setup) for `django.setup()` and you'll see that one of the main roles of this function is to set up logging according to your settings. [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) portion of the docs it mentions a scenario where using django.setup() is required to utilize logging:

> If you’re using components of Django “standalone” – for example,
>   writing a Python script which loads some Django templates and renders
>   them, or uses the ORM to fetch some data – there’s one more step
>   you’ll need in addition to configuring settings.

I can't tell what your project does, but the test you are running seems to fall into the category of "standalone".

Looking into the source `django.setup()` in part calls the following

```
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
```

And the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/utils/log.py#L67) for that function does the following:

```
def configure_logging(logging_config, logging_settings):
    if logging_config:
        # First find the logging configuration function ...
        logging_config_func = import_string(logging_config)

        logging.config.dictConfig(DEFAULT_LOGGING)

        # ... then invoke it with the logging settings
        if logging_settings:
            logging_config_func(logging_settings)
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. However, the issue still appears in the project when I serve a page with a logging call.

Comment: Do you have an example in the project of where the logging fails? Perhaps there are two separate issues?